# Iphone AsiHttpRequest authentification RESTService

Tags: iphone, authentication, asihttprequest

i try to connect my application on REST.

I don't understand, when i try to connect in a first time, it's fail (403). And when I retry, it is good ! (I don't have valide certificate at this time)

```
        request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUsername:login];
    [request setPassword:password];
    [request setDelegate:delegate];
    [request setRequestMethod:GET];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    /*I keep my login/pass*/
    [request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:YES];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
    [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];
    [request setPersistentConnectionTimeoutSeconds:15.0];
    [request setUseCookiePersistence:YES];
    /**/
    [request startSynchronous];
```

And log:

```
   requestUrl:https://urlToLogin

 login:user

 pwd:pwduser


 Starting synchronous request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x504fc00>

 Request #1 will use connection #1

 ===Used: 0 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===

 Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x504fc00> received response headers

 Got a keep-alive header, will keep this connection open for 15.000000 seconds

 Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x504fc00> finished downloading data (118 bytes)

 Request #1 finished using connection #1

 codeResponce:403

 requestUrl:https://urlToLogin

 login:user

 pwd:pwduser

 Starting synchronous request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x603a600>

 Request #2 will use connection #1

 Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x603a600> received response headers

 Got a keep-alive header, will keep this connection open for 15.000000 seconds

 ===Used: 138 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===

 Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x603a600> finished downloading data (20 bytes)

 Request #2 finished using connection #1

 Request finished: <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x603a600>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might not be your app that's wrong but the server you're trying to connect to - 403 means forbidden so retrying shouldn't fix it.

What are you trying to connect to?